# Adding text to screen space with reailtykit, swift and swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, arkit, realitykit

**How to add text to screen space in RealityKit/SwiftUI?**

All the tutorials online are about adding text to screen space with UIKit/Scene Kit, but it never uses SwiftUI/RealityKit. Even Apple's uses UIKit for most of their examples!

[Apple's example of screen space](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_screen_annotations_for_objects_in_an_ar_experience)

It's not a straightforward conversion from Apple's explain into SwiftUI/RealityKit. Apple would get the 2d screen point, but then update the UIText's view frame with that 2d screen point.

> To put the annotation in the right place on the screen, ask the ARView
> to convert its entity’s world location to a 2D screen point.
>
> ```
> guard let projectedPoint = arView.project(note.position) else { return }
> ```

All I have right now is a tap handler that would raycast to the tap location. From that I have world coordinates, which I use for my anchor position. I created a mesh of text, but when adding to the anchor, it exists in world space and isn't aligned properly

```
let raycastResults = self.raycast(from: tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .any)
        
guard let raycastFirstResult: ARRaycastResult = raycastRes.first else { return }

let position = raycastFirstResult.worldTransform
let mesh = MeshResource.generateText("Test")
```

Has anyone added text to world space using SwiftUI/RealityKit before?

Comment: Most likely is impossible, just used the UIKit instead.